# how to build maven modules in parallel

Tags: maven

i'm building my parent-pom in jenkins, the parent-pom contains call to many modules and i'm wondering if there's an alternative other than `mvn -e -T 4 clean install` to build multi-modules in parallel with maven

Comment: What do you mean by `..it doesn't seem to be good for my project`?

Comment: i'm just searching for other alternatives

Comment: If you want an alternative, you should explain why the standard way is not good (enough) for your purposes.

Comment: the -T option restricts you to work with Maven-3 + Thread Safe problems

Comment: What do you mean by `the -T option restricts you to work with Maven-3 + Thread Safe problems`? What are the problems?

Comment: @khmarbaise to work with -T option you have to build your project with  maven-3 , and some of my project dependencies are not thread safe it raises warnings

Comment: It seemed to me you don't understand the handling of `-T`...Building your project in parallel has nothing to do if your dependencies are thread safe or not.....

Comment: You only need to ask yourself if your _maven plugins_ are thread safe